# How to extract the first digit in an array from an online json file in p5.js?

Tags: p5.js

I am trying to apply substring, but I guess I'm doing something wrong. I have little experience in coding and would appreciate on any comments. Maybe the syntax or the order is wrong. Please help:)

```
let earthquakes;
let url = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson';

function setup() {
setInterval(atnaujinkData,500)
}

function atnaujinkData(){
loadJSON(url,'geojson', gotData); 
}

function gotData(data){   
earthquakes = data.features;
} 

function draw(){
//background(0);
if(earthquakes){
for (var i = 0; i < earthquakes.length; i++)
{
let dydis = abs(round(earthquakes[i].properties.mag*1000));
let numeris = dydis.substring(0,1);

createElement('h1',numeris);
fill(100,255,255,60);
//createElement('h1',earthquakes[i].properties.place);
} 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bare in mind `substring()` works on strings and `numeris` is a number, so you'd need to convert it to a string beforehand:

```
let numeris = dydis.toString().substring(0,1);
```

(I recommend getting into the habbit of indenting/formatting code.
On the long run you'll spend more time reading (more complex) code than actually writing the code, so making the code easier to read will save you time.)